# receive TCP/IP data on a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets

I have a custom device with a TCP/IP stack implemented that's sending a byte each 5 seconds to a remote IP.

On that remote IP, I'm building a site with rails 3.1.3 that will have to receive, store and display the data sent by the custom device.

I was thinking on having a TCP Socket running in the background, something like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm), but i don't have a clue on how to integrate this with a rails site. Where to place it, how to start it and how to propagate the data to the views.

Does anybody have a clue on how shall I proceed?

Comment: Did you found any way? I am also facing the same scenario.

Comment: @soundar, I posted an answer with my solution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I created a raketask that starts a TCP Server that will handle messages.

Note: This code has more than a year so I'm not 100% sure how it behaves, but I think the core part is this:

```
@server = TCPServer.new(@host, port)

loop do
  Thread.start(@server.accept) do |tcpSocket|
    port, ip = Socket.unpack_sockaddr_in(tcpSocket.getpeername)
    begin
      loop do 
        line = tcpSocket.recv(100).strip   # Read lines from the socket
        handle_message line # method to handle messages from the socket
      end
    rescue SystemCallError
      #close the sockets logic
    end
  end
end
```